# Rosbridge c++/python client

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros User,
I am trying to use rosbridge. I saw there is a good tutorial for using a javascript client through roslibjs, but I cannot found any example on C++/python client
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266293/rosbridge-c++/python-client/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2017-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've not tested, but here we have a ROS Bridge Client in Python that can be used for reference:

http://www.pythonexample.com/code/rosbridge%20turtlesim%20client/

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmp52](https://answers.ros.org/users/44060/mmp52/) on 2019-07-16**:
Hey, this link is dead I believe, is there any progress in this topic?
May you share this with me?

**Comment by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on 2019-11-12**:
This might help.. https://github.com/gramaziokohler/roslibpy